# Non breaking spaces are rendered as regular space in vue template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

When I used `&nbsp;` in Vue template, in browser they are rendered as regular space.

```
<template>
  <p>
     sample text in&nbsp;sample text 
     <strong>lorem ipsum</strong>
   </p>
</template>
```

Final render in browser looks like:

sample text in sample text **lorem ipsum**

My question is how to write non breaking spaces in template?

Comment: Have you checked this: https://cli.vuejs.org/migrating-from-v3/#vue-cli-service ?

Comment: How are you determining that the rendered space is a normal space and not a non-breaking space character?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<p>
 sample text in{{'\xa0'}}sample text 
 <strong>lorem ipsum</strong>
<p>
```

Try to use the JavaScript escape code and not the HTML entity.